# AJAX chat system not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I can't seem to work this one out. Been a few days and still no progress after re-writing it more times than I can count on my hands.

Here is the Javascript (On same page as html)

Summary: User types text into the input box. That gets sent off to be processed, which then gets sent back and displayed on the screen in the box ID'd as DisplayText on the html page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SendText() {
        if (document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML == "") {
            return;
        } else
        {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("DisplayText").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            Text = document.getElementById("Text").value;
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "php/Test.php?Chat=" + Text, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is the HTML (Same page as the script)

```
<div>
    <p>
        <span id="DisplayText">
            TEXT GOES HERE
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
<form action="" onsubmit="SendText();">
    <input type="" name="" id="Text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="Send" />
</form>
```

The PHP code is here

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("Connect.php");
$Connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "chatsystem");
$Create = "CREATE TABLE " . $_SESSION["Username"] . "Chat(Username VARCHAR(255), Chat VARCHAR(255))";
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$DatabaseExist = $Connection->query("SELECT 1 FROM " . $_SESSION["Username"] . "Chat");
if ($DatabaseExist !== false) {
    echo "Database exists";
    doSomething();
} else {
    echo "Database does not exist";
    mysqli_query($Connection, $Create);
    doSomething();
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function doSomething() {
    // Get the sent chat
    $Input = $_REQUEST["Chat"];
    // Insert into the database the new chat sent
    mysqli_query($Connection, "INSERT INTO " . $_SESSION["Username"] . "chat (`Username`, `Chat`) VALUES ('$_SESSION[Username], '$Input')");
    // Select everything from the database
    $Result = $Connection->query("SELECT * FROM " . $_SESSION["Username"] . "Chat");
    // Display everything from the database in an orderly fashion
    // --
    // For the length of the database
    // Append to a variable the next table row
    // --
    while ($Row = $Result->fetch_array()) {
        // Make Variable accessable
        global $Input;
        // Append username to the return value
        $Input = $Input . $Row["Username"] . " : ";
        // Append chat to the return value
        $Input = $Input . $Row["Chat"] . "<br />";
    }
}
// Will return the value
echo $Input;
?>
```

My connection to the Database is fine. I'm using it on other pages that work.
So lets assume that's not the problem. :P

Any help or insight from anyone who knows or can think of something that is wrong, I would be very grateful for.
I'm new to AJAX.

Comment: use javascript frameworks (JQuery recommended) for this purpose as far as ajax concerns. see this tutorial, http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/60-simple-long-polling-example-with-javascript-and-jquery for long polling technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st :** use input's `value` property instead `innerHTML`

eg. use

```
if (document.getElementById("Text").value == "")
```

instead of

```
if (document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML == "")
```

**2nd :** use `return false;` at the form's `onsubmit` event; to **prevent current page to be refreshed** as you are using ajax. Otherwise the page will get refreshed and it wont display the php page's output,

eg. use

```
onsubmit="SendText(); return false;"
```

instead of just

```
onsubmit="SendText();"
```

Comment: As your answer had the most input to give me I've marked it as the answer. Because of both these answers it's shaved quiet a bit of time off for me, trying to work out why it was refreshing would of been a struggle. So thank you.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli hmmm right but sql injection is server side concerns; its  not a part of the question.

Comment: @BhaveshGangani i am very sorry... that comment was supposed to go to the comment in my own answer... sorry about that..

Answer (score 1):

You do a wrong test with

```
if (document.getElementById("Text").innerHTML == "")
```

It should be the same way you use to get the text for sending in the AJAX

```
if (document.getElementById("Text").value == "")
```

So check its `value` property and not its `innerHTML` as `input` elements do not have html content..

---

Be careful though because your code is wide-open to [SQL injection attacks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: I'm trying to get it working, then I'm going to strip the text from all characters except alphabetical and numerical, that should deal with a few SQL Injection attacks? However thank you for this code. It's helped me to be able to debug it.

Comment: @Hamedar the best protection against injections is to use prepared statements that accept user input only as parameters and not a string concatenation..

Comment: Wouldn't the protection be sufficient enough to stop any and all injection attacks if I strip all characters that are not alphabetical and/or numerical? That way they have no ability to use php and/or sql coding?

If they can't communicate with the database they can't cause any problems.

However I can see what you mean, a prepared statement would simply remove any and all ability to do anything.

Comment: @Hamedar most likely.. but at the server side right ? and that would work only when using data as strings in your sql so that they are wrapped in `'` .. for example your  `$_SESSION["Username"]` can also be abused for sql injection. beware of encoded strings as well.. there are many tricks a hacker can employ to bypass protection..

Comment: Is their another way that's less vulnerable to attack to handle login? I only know of session storage to do it. Otherwise how can you check if a user is logged in every time they visit a new page? I suppose Cookies can do it? That way you could also keep them logged in after they leave the page. But what sort of protection does a cookie have over session?

Answer (score 0):

Try AJAX Long Polling technique for chat application. Here is example

http://portal.bluejack.binus.ac.id/tutorials/webchatapplicationusinglong-pollingtechnologywithphpandajax

Comment: Great read. Will certainly use it's resources to assist me. Thank you.